Cohort saliency analysis in Python
I trained a CNN model to predict clinically relevant parameters by using images as inputs. Now I want to do a cohort GradCAM analysis on the images that were used in the test set in order to see where the model was focusing. I have already generated the heatmaps for each individual patient but now I am not sure how to proceed. One thought that I have is to sum up all the heatmaps and take the mean out of this summation. Any suggestions would be helpfull.

For starters: what is "GradCAM"?

StackOverflow is for specific programming quesitons. You might get better answers to your question if you repost over at the Cross Validated StackExchange.
